# AutoLayout, subviews and their parent's frame

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a feeling I didn't properly understand how autolayout works, especially regarding frame sizes and subviews. The example below is using FLKAutoLayout, but it's really simple:

```
labelOne.alignLeadingEdgeWithView(parent, predicate: ">=5")
labelOne.alignTrailingEdgeWithView(parent, predicate: nil)
labelOne.alignTopEdgeWithView(parent, predicate: nil)

labelTwo.alignLeadingEdgeWithView(parent, predicate: ">=5")
labelTwo.constrainTopSpaceToView(labelOne, predicate: "20")
labelTwo.alignBottomEdgeWithView(parent, predicate: "-5")
labelTwo.alignTrailingEdgeWithView(parent, predicate: nil)
```

The labels should have a left padding of at least `5`, a padding of `20` between them, and a bottom padding of `5`.

Do I need to `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` on the parent too, for it to have a proper frame?

Shouldn't `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` be enough? What if I have a complex subview composition, I want to use autoLayout for them, but not for the parent, which is a subview inside another container?

The constraint that gets broken if I don't `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` to the parent is:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint: 0x7bb84e90> H:|-(>=5)-[UILabel:0x7bb89a70'test text'] ((null), (null))",
"<NSLayoutConstraint: 0x7bb4d3c0> (null) ((null), (null))",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint: 0x7bb865a0> H:[UIView:0x7bb7ddc0(0)] ((null), (null))"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint: 0x7bb4d3c0> (null) ((null), (null))
```

I realize I need to better understand autoLayout, I'd just like to know where I'm missing information and what that is.

Comment: This is for subviews setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, not for a parent view when using auto layout. So, that part of your question is answered. However, if you have a view that is a subclass of another view, such that you have a subview of a subview of a subview, then all subviews EVEN if they are the parent of another view will require "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints", the only view that won't require this with auto layout is the Parent view of all views or the view that actually has a FRAME defined by the system or yourself

Comment: So there's no way to tell a view 'hey, grow enough to encompass your subviews + the paddings defined by constraints' :)? Meaning that in the example above, if I want the `parent` to be inside another, main, container, I need to either provide a hardcoded frame for it, or `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` on it and position it in the main container also with autoLayout, right?